# Correct use of 惹人心烦: is 然而我不要惹人心烦 a suitable way to say you don't want to be a pain in the neck?

Tags: mandarin, word-choice, idioms

I am not sure if I used the idiom 惹人心烦 correctly. This is the sentence I used:

> 好啊，然而我不要惹人心烦。

Would that be a good use of it or is there a better way of saying you don't want to be a pain in the neck for someone?

Comment: 惹人心烦 is not an idiom (chengyu). A better phrase would be 我不想整天唠叨[láo dāo] to imply that you don't want to be a constant pain in the neck for someone by nagging whole day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks fine to me.  But you could say 不好意思麻烦你 = sorry for bothering you.  To me 麻烦你 sounds like a more colloquial way of talking about bothering someone or being a trouble for someone.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a little strange to me.

*Incidentally, one can get beaten up in school simply by referring to oneself as one.* - Sheldon Cooper

Here `人` maps quite well to `one` as a third person neutral pronoun, but **more often than not**, is used to refer to oneself, such as `me` or `us` (although it can also refer to `you`, `her` or `them`, in most contexts, it points to self).

So `惹` for `make`, `人` for `one`, `心` for `heart (mood)`, `烦` for `annoyed`: `惹人心烦` literally means `make one annoyed`.

Examples:

这天气真是惹人心烦。(The weather really makes one annoyed. (me or us))

楼上的邻居真是惹人心烦。(The upstairs neighbor really makes one annoyed. (me or us))

对你/她来说，那也许是惹人心烦的吧！(you/her)

--

The correct way to say you don't want to be a pain in the neck for someone is `我不想惹你心烦` （yes, you can substitute `人` directly with `你` if you are talking to that person). On the other hand,  `我不想让你麻烦` or `我不想麻烦你` means something different, something similar to `I don't want to bother you` or `I don't want to trouble you`). LadyP's interpretation of `麻烦你` is correct.